# Convert a CHM file to appropriate Intellisense-compatible XML

Tags: .net, intellisense, chm

A vendor has supplied their .NET API with documentation in the form of a Windows CHM.

The documentation is remarkably high quality, and would be very helpful if it actually appeared in Visual Studio while using their library.

I would presume it is possible, given that it is just a mapping from HTML to XML. There may be data missing, but for a one-off it could probably be added manually.

Has anyone reverse-engineered the xml file required to drive Intellisense from a CHM before?

Thanks

Comment: Open the Chm in 7-zip and you'll see what you're up against. It ain't pretty.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are on the wrong track here. Yes you can convert HTML to XML using some generalized tool, but that just means that html markup is translated to the some XML like tag syntax for the html formatting, and tags are properly closed.

VS-intellisense probably expects a special XML structure, and you need to extract that using a specialized parser/transformation.

Moreover the decompiled CHM is a bunch of html + a couple of indexes in XML, which you probably need to transform into one intellisense XML

At the very least you need to extract the keyword-topic mapping and convert the topic body to whatever markup syntax the intellisense viewer uses.

All and all, not trivial and potentially specific for each CHM (or at least for the tool that generates it), since essentially CHM can contain nearly the full spec of html, and the original structure might need to be guessed and extracted by own code.